# Is using the present tense to depict a future state allowed?

Tags: grammar, verbs, tenses

> When I complete it, I will feel that everything **is** fine.

Or,

> I will feel (that) everything **is** fine, when I complete it.

Should 'is' be 'will be', because feeling that 'everything is fine' will occur in the future?

I'm trying to depict a state that will be the present in the future, not a state that will happen *after* or *later than* some point in the future.

Comment: There is no future tense in English. One may refer to the future in many ways, including the simple present, the present progressive, other modal auxiliaries (_may, can, would, should, must,_ etc), and various special constructions (_be going to, have to, ought to, be to,_ etc). _Will_ is not used nearly as often in English as you seem to have been told.

Answer (score 2):

*Is* is the correct form here; in this case, the time in the subordinate clause "that everything is fine" is interpreted relative to the time in the matrix clause "I will feel that […]". The same construction even allows the *past* tense, as in this example:

> *Subjective experiences of relative success or failure* flow from these evaluations, viewed in the light of one's prior expectations (e.g., among students who earn a B, any who expected a lower grade will feel successful but any who expected an A will feel that they **failed** to accomplish what they should have). [[link](https://books.google.com/books?id=wqnmAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA141&dq=failed); italics in original, boldface mine]

where *failed* is in the past tense to indicate that the (perceived) failure predates the feeling of it. (The present perfect, *have failed*, would also work here, but the simple present, *fail*, would not.)

If you have access to the *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (*CGEL*), this construction is discussed in Chapter 3 ("The verb"), § 4.2.6 ("Future interpretation of a non-deictic present tense"), page 136, as well as in § 4.3.4 ("Non-deictic anteriority"), page 139. The details are surprisingly subtle, but you don't necessarily need to understand all of them to find the explanation and examples useful.

---

Incidentally, if we "flipped" the sentence from future time to past time, we would use the past tense for all three verbs:

> When I completed it, I felt that everything **was** fine.

This asymmetry between handling of past time and future time is pervasive in English; we arguably don't even really have a future tense, just a past tense, a non-past tense, and various rules for when future time can, must, or must not be indicated in a special way.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the nature of the task. If completion of it results in an actual change then ***is*** is correct but if the task is only a stage in a process then ***will be*** is correct.

For example you might say "When I have rewired the house I will know that the electrical system ***is*** safe" but "When I have worked out the wiring scheme and calculated the loads I will know that the electrical system ***will be*** safe".

The difference is that all the planning in the world will not actually make the house safe to live in, the old dangerous wiring will still be there until it is physically replaced. But note that the completed task version (...will know that...is...) is much more common

Answer (score 0):

The **Is** will stay unless you wish leave out the verb *to feel* and rewrite as:

*When I complete my work everything will be fine.*

Or

*Everything will be fine when I complete my work.* (Better)